# Confusion finding Operator Norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T \in Hom(l_{2}(\mathbb{N}),l_{2}(\mathbb{N}))$ be given by,

$(Tf)(n) = f(n) + f(n+1)$

with $||f|| = ||f||_{2}$

1) Compute the operator norm of T.

- Do I use $||T|| = Sup (\frac{||Af||}{||f||}$) with $f \ne 0$?

2) How do I find the eigenvalues of T?

- Do I use $Tv = \lambda v$ ?

3) Can I use this information to show surjectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

$(x+y)^2 \leq 2(x^2 + y^2) $, hence:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (f(n)+f(n+1))^2 \leq
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2(f(n)^2+f(n+1)^2) = 2(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (f(n))^2 +
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (f(n+1))^2) = 4||f||^2$
Hence $||T(f)||^2 \leq 4||f||^2$

$||T(f)|| \leq 2||f||$

Thus $||T|| \leq 2$ from properties of operator.

We can define $f_0$:
Let $f_0(n) := 1$ for all $n$ constantly.

We have $T(f_0)=2$

Thus $||T||$ cannot be less than 2.

$||T|| = 2$.

Second question:

From $T(f) = \lambda f$ we have: $f(n)+f(n+1) = \lambda f(n) $

So it must be: $f(n+1) = (\lambda-1)f(n)$
Let $a := f(1)$ We have candidates for eigenvectors of form:
$f(n) = a \cdot (\lambda -1)^n $ - geometrical sequences.
$|\lambda -1|<1$ because $\sum_{1}^{\infty} f(n)^2$ must be convergent.

Hence $\lambda \in (0,2) $ are all eigenvalues of $T$ and $f(n) = a \cdot (\lambda -1)^n $  are it's eigenvectors.

Comment: Your $f_0$ doesn't belong to $l_2(\mathbb{N})$. Make it $f_k(n) = 1$ for $n \leqslant k$ and $f_k(n) = 0$ for $n > k$. Then you get arbitrarily close to $2$.

Comment: yes ! i forgot this

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks to both comments. To find the eigenvalues do I use the norm of T being 2 and deduce that the only eigenvalue of T is 2 from $||Tv|| = ||\lambda v|| $ ?

Comment: @Sean No, that's not correct. In fact, all eigenvalues of $T$ have modulus strictly smaller than $2$. It's probably easier to find the eigenvalues of $U = T - I$, that is, $(Uf)(n) = f(n+1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks

Comment: i made update for second question in my answer.

Comment: Ok I take it T is not surjective,